# ffmpeg osx error while writing file : "Unrecognized option 'preset'.Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Tags: python, ffmpeg, osx-elcapitan, moviepy

I have the following simple Python Code:

```
yellow_output = 'test_videos_output/solidYellowleft.mp4'
clip1 = VideoFileClip("test_videos/solidYellowLeft.mp4")
yellow_clip = clip1.fl_image(process_image)
yellow_clip.write_videofile(yellow_output, audio=False)
```

The "process_image" function just returns what you give it (created for testing purposes).

Running Python 3.5.4, ffmpeg 2.8.6, on OSX 10.11.6

I get the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file test_videos_output/solidWwhiteright.mp4:

 b"Unrecognized option 'preset'.\nError splitting the argument list: Option not found\n"
```

the video file is not generated; how to get rid of this error; so I can generate the MP4 file?

Note: the same code runs happily on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the same problem mentioned here:
https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/657

Try the following from this comment:
https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/657#issuecomment-355858936

`conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg`

Comment: @asabbah Glad to hear! Could you please set the question as answered if your problem has been solved? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

For me

`conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg`

which installed `pytorch::ffmpeg-4.3-hf484d3e_0`

specifically **didn't work**.

However simply doing

`conda update ffmpeg`

which installed `pkgs/main::ffmpeg-4.2.2-h20bf706_0`

solved this problem for me.

Comment: Same for me. I'm guessing there is a mismatch caused by some packages being installed from `conda-forge` and some not. My `moviepy` is from `conda-forge`, however; version is `1.0.3-pyhd8ed1ab_1`.

Answer (score 0):

this problem will come when you set worng path to your destination
if it is correct then you can check https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/657.

if window user you can install using this command `pip install --index-url pypi.anaconda.org/nithin/conda-forge imageio-ffmpeg`to rectify the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg didn't solve it. So I created new environment than I installed these packages in order: numpy -> moviepy -> opencv.

The problem here is, i think, both moviepy and opencv installs ffmpeg while they are installed and one of them is not competable with this setup.

Comment: The accepted solution of `conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg` also doesn't solve the problem for me. But neither does this answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Do not use 4.3 version. Degrading back to 4.2.2 solved my problem.

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg=4.2.2
```